# How to pass system variable or package option to tests with testthat

Tags: r, dplyr, testthat

I have a commonly structured R project with a test folder that contains all my unit tests, implemented with `testthat`. Furthermore, `testthat` creates the root folder tests and places a `testthat.R` file in with the following lines

```
library(testthat)
library(MyPackage)
test_check("MyPackage")
```

Now, some of the functionality used within the tests require a `Sys.env` to be set. In order to avoid setting it manually in every test file, my exepectation was that when placing a proper line before the `test_check("MyPackage")` command, all subsequent tests can query the system variable. Example:

```
library(testthat)
library(MyPackage)
Sys.setenv("test123" = "test")
test_check("MyPackage")
```

Inside a specific **test file:**

```
testthat::test_that("test os for testing", {
  print(Sys.getenv("test123"))
  os <- Sys.info()["sysname"]
  testthat::expect_true(os %in% c("Windows", "Linux"))
})
```

When hitting *"Test Package"* I see that the output of `print(Sys.getenv("test123"))` is `""`. So my guess is that the environment is reset. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: This works; but you need to use `Sys.setenv` correctly. The code you've posted will raise an error on `Sys.setenv`. After fixing the error, it works: `Sys.setenv(test123 = "test")` — Another potential issue is that `print` inside a `test_that` stanza will be swallowed instead of displayed. This is normal, and unrelated to the issue of environment variables.

Comment: If you don't need this environment variable for all tests, you could use the package [`withr`](https://withr.r-lib.org/index.html) to temporarily set this env-var in some tests (take a look at [`with_envvar()`](https://withr.r-lib.org/reference/with_envvar.html)). This is described in the vignette ["Test fixtures"](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/test-fixtures.html#test-fixtures) of `testthat`.

Comment: One advantage of using `withr::with_envvar` is that you can test that your functions fail gracefully/properly in the _absence_ of that envvar, simpler to do when you control it per-test. (Or ... you can set it in `setup.R` and temporarily remove it for _one_ test with `with_envvar`.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry your are right of course. This was just a copy paste error. However, it still seems not to work, as the test fails. My test is true when I write Sys.setenv(test123 = "test") just before the function call. This said, it seems like the variable is just reseted inside the test

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the reported behaviour with a simple test package, running R 4.3.0 and **testthat** 3.1.7.  Your question will likely be closed, but I'll share the package anyway ...

```bash
$ R CMD build addOne
$ R CMD check addOne_0.0-0.tar.gz
```

```
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘testthat.R’
 OK
```

---

`DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: addOne
Version: 0.0-0
License: GPL (>= 2)
Description: A (one paragraph) description of what
  the package does and why it may be useful.
Title: My First Collection of Functions
Author: Mikael Jagan [aut, cre]
Maintainer: Mikael Jagan <Mikael.Jagan@some.domain.net>
Suggests: testthat
Config/testthat/edition: 3
```

`NAMESPACE`:

```r
export(addOne)
```

`R/addOne.R`:

```r
addOne <- function(x) as.double(x) + 1
```

`man/addOne.Rd`:

```latex
\name{addOne}
\alias{addOne}
\title{Add one to a number}
\description{Adds one to a number.}
\usage{addOne(x)}
\arguments{
\item{x}{A number.}
}
\examples{
stopifnot(identical(addOne(0), 1))
}
```

`tests/testthat.R`:

```r
library(testthat)
library(addOne)
Sys.setenv(SOMEVAR = "someval")
stopifnot(identical(Sys.getenv("SOMEVAR"), "someval"))
test_check("addOne")
```

`tests/testthat/test-addOne.R`:

```r
stopifnot(identical(Sys.getenv("SOMEVAR"), "someval"))
test_that("zzz", expect_identical(Sys.getenv("SOMEVAR"), "someval"))
```

Comment: seems like for me that only works when running Rcheck, but not when running "Test Package", at least on RStudio Server edition running on Ubuntu

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to ask a different question, about RStudio specifically.  You can link to this question if it helps.  You might want to investigate a bit more, too.  For example, does the problem occur on RStudio Desktop, or is it limited to RStudio Server?